# Why $event.messageData from serial port event is empty?

Tags: powershell, arduino

I'm trying to receive serial data from Arduino asynchronously via "DataReceived" event, but it $event.messageData is always empty.

Here's my code so far:

```
$port = New-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM7,9600,None,8,one
$port.Open()
$port | Format-List -Property *
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $port -EventName "DataReceived" -Action {
  $event | Format-List -Property * | Out-Host
}
```

Here's the output:

```
PORT

BaseStream             : System.IO.Ports.SerialStream
BaudRate               : 9600
BreakState             : False
BytesToWrite           : 0
BytesToRead            : 0
CDHolding              : False
CtsHolding             : False
DataBits               : 8
DiscardNull            : False
DsrHolding             : False
DtrEnable              : False
Encoding               : System.Text.ASCIIEncoding
Handshake              : None
IsOpen                 : True
NewLine                :

Parity                 : None
ParityReplace          : 63
PortName               : COM7
ReadBufferSize         : 4096
ReadTimeout            : -1
ReceivedBytesThreshold : 1
RtsEnable              : False
StopBits               : One
WriteBufferSize        : 2048
WriteTimeout           : -1
Site                   :
Container              :

EVENT

ComputerName     :
RunspaceId       : 67c40d50-5a9b-4022-974e-0a6a6518c2af
EventIdentifier  : 11
Sender           : System.IO.Ports.SerialPort
SourceEventArgs  : System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs
SourceArgs       : {COM7, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs}
SourceIdentifier : 26c24bdb-8085-4e88-828e-44cb7897e416
TimeGenerated    : 6/16/2019 12:52:39 AM
MessageData      :
```

On the arduino side the code is:

```
Serial.printlf("ready")
```

When I use syncronous approach everything works

```
$port = New-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM7,9600,None,8,one
$port.Open()
$port.ReadLine()
```

Output

```
ready
ready
ready
...
```

Please, help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$event.MessageData` is not the right property to query - it contains custom data passed to the 
`-MessageData` parameter when raising a *custom* event via the [`New-Event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-event)  cmdlet.

For .NET-originated events, it is generally the automatic `$EventArgs` variable that contains the event-specific data.

In the specific case of the `[System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]` type's `DataReceived` event, however, it seems that the data isn't actually passed as an event *argument*, and you must instead use the `$Sender` object to gain access to the originating `[System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]` instance in order to call its `.ReadExisting()` method, judging by the [sample code in the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=netframework-4.8#examples):

```
$eventJob = 
  Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $port -EventName "DataReceived" -Action {
    $Sender.ReadExisting() | Out-Host
  }
```

Comment: How do you write this in powershell? I don't get it. All the docs referring to this, are all about C#, nothing useful for powershell. I would love to see a functioning powersehll implementation for writing and reading on the COM port. E.g. connecting to a serial modem and sending AT commands and being able to receive the response.

Comment: @not2qubit, I see that you've since posted a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76250070/45375), which was the right thing to do. (I personally won't be of much help in this subject matter.)

Comment: I solved it there now. And you should always add a name to the handler via `-SourceIdentifier SOME_NAME`. Thanks.